# Core Data Nil Object Model Error

Tags: objective-c

Keep getting  nil object model and went through several other posts and all the steps I could find.

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@“DBname” withExtension:@"momd"];
```

- DBname matches the DBname.xcdatamodel file name
- DBname.xcdatamodel is in copy bundle resources and source file lists
- did a clean and build and restart
- The file exists in finder
- No conflicting duplicate files
- Completed fresh app install

Is there another step to take to find the model path.

Comment: just guessing, but the docs say the file name should be DBname.momd  (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with extension mom rather then momd. Added a condition to the core data stack.

```
//try first extension 

modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"modelFile" withExtension:@"momd"];

if (!modelURL)
{
    //try another extention
    modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"modelFile" withExtension:@"mom"];
}
```